# how to load different type of Driver.class from jar file in run time in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

hello i am making a query builder who access different type of databases like ms-aceess,Mysql,Oracle etc..

i make a JFrame where user choose a database and give username and password and application connect to that database but i do not know that how to load a driver.class file from to the jar  file

```
   package design;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.sql.*;
public class Connect_to_database {
    Panel_Connection pc;
    Connection con;
    ResultSet result;
    Statement stm;
     ClassLoader cl;
     Class cls;
    public Connect_to_database(Panel_Connection pc) {
        this.pc=pc;
        if(pc.database_name.equals("MySQL")){
        loadMySQLDriver();
        }

        if(pc.database_name.equals("Oracle")){
            loadOracleDriver();
            }
        if(pc.database_name.equals("MS-Access")){
            loadMS_AccessDNS();
            }

        try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student","root","anil");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
    private void loadMS_AccessDNS() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void loadOracleDriver() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void loadMySQLDriver(){
         File file = new File("F:\\database server\\mysql\\com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\\com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\\mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar");

            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = file.toURI().toURL();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };

           cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

            try {
                cls =cl.loadClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


}
```

it give me error

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at design.Connect_to_database.<init>(Connect_to_database.java:19)
    at design.Panel_Connection.actionPerformed(Panel_Connection.java:121)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You load the Driver jar in your classpath. I'm fairly certain you can't use it embedded in your jar without writing a custom class-loader.

Comment: but application connect many types of databases like-ms-access,Mysql,Oracle than should i set more than 5 database class path in classpath variable

Comment: If you have to connect to five different databases then yes. You'll need all five database drivers in your classpath.

Comment: You can extend your classpath by creating a custom classloader, BUT IT'S NOT WORTH IT - ahem, sorry for the yelling. You could go the OSGi route and dynamically extend you classpath, but that kind of integration comes with a complexity cost.

Comment: can you give me any example with code so that understand properly